# How to find the partial fractions of the given irreducible equation?

Tags: partial-fractions

$$H(z) = \frac{(z^2 + \frac 13 z)(z^2 -\frac 78 z)}{(z^2 - 2z +2)(z^2 -\frac 34z + \frac 18)}.$$
How can i find the partial fractions of the given function above? I know the equation in the denominator is irreducible. Can anyone solve this equation?

Comment: Partial fractions over what ring/field?

Comment: I dont know what you mean by ring/field.. I have to decompose the given function using partial fractions.

Comment: Is this a problem in complex variables?

Comment: No its not in complex variables. This problem was to decompose the given function to H1(z) and H2(z) and make it in a cascade form

Answer (score 0):

Hint...the partial fractions will take the form $$1+\frac{Az+B}{z^2-2z+2}+\frac{C}{z-\frac 12}+\frac{D}{z-\frac 14}$$

Answer (score 0):

Let's write your rational function as
$$
{{\left( {z^{\,2}  + 1/3\,z} \right)\left( {z^{\,2}  - 7/8\,z} \right)} \over {\left( {z^{\,2}  - 2\,z + 2} \right)\left( {z^{\,2}  - 3/4\,z + 1/8\,} \right)}} = z^{\,2} {{\left( {z + 1/3} \right)\left( {z - 7/8} \right)} \over {\left( {z^{\,2}  - 2\,z + 2} \right)\left( {z^{\,2}  - 3/4\,z + 1/8\,} \right)}}
$$

The term following $z^2$ is the ratio of a polynomial of $2$nd degree
with a polynomial of $4$th degree.

Since you said that you are not going to work in the complex field,
remaining in the real one, you can perform the partial fraction decomposition
keeping the non-decomposable factors at the denominator with $2$nd degree
but then putting a $1$st degree polynomial at the numerator of each summand.

That is you can put
$$
{{\left( {z + 1/3} \right)\left( {z - 7/8} \right)} \over {\left( {z^{\,2}  - 2\,z + 2} \right)\left( {z^{\,2}  - 3/4\,z + 1/8\,} \right)}} = {{\left( {a\,z + b} \right)} \over {\left( {z^{\,2}  - 2\,z + 2} \right)}} + {{\left( {c\,z + d} \right)} \over {\left( {z^{\,2}  - 3/4\,z + 1/8\,} \right)}}
$$

Now you can solve for the four unknowns $a,b,c,d$ in various ways.
The most common one is to perform the sum in the RHS, and then equate the coefficients at the numerator.
Another possible way is to assign to $z$ four "easy" values and solve the $4 \times 4$ linear system.
Either way you reach to 
$$
a = {1 \over {15}}\quad b = {{17} \over {15}}\quad c =  - {1 \over {15}}\quad b =  - {{13} \over {60}}
$$